# JQuery - on()-Method / dynamic handler

Tags: jquery

i have a waitinglist and a list of participants. The admin can add users to the list of participants by clicking on a div besides the users name on the waiting list.

After clicking on the div to add someone to the participants list an ajax request will be called -> this request updates the status of the user in the database and - if the ajax request was successful  - adds the user to the participants list without reloading the page. So it looks like the list will be refreshed from the database but the user is added to the list via JQuery and the database operation is done in the back.

Additionally the admin can delete users from the list of participants. This happens with the div .event_list_cancel - when the admin clicks on that the user will be deleted from the participants list and will be added to the waiting list again. The strange thing is, that i can only add/delete users to the list/from the list when i initially entered the page. When i e.g. moved a user from the waiting to the participants list and then will change it back by clicking on the "delete-div" in the participants list, nothing happens. If i refresh the site and all will be generated fresh from the database - then it works. I hoped that the JQuery on()-method will fix this, because the element after adding/deleting will be there before the DOM loaded, but nothing happens.... How can i solve this ?

I hope it's not to confusing explained.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the documentation and read the section about **[Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)**.

Basically, if you use `on` like this:

```
$(".some_button").on("click",function(){});
```

Then this event is going to be bound directly to each element which matches your selector.  If new elements are added to the DOM that match the selector, they will not be added.

If however, you use it like this:

```
$("#my_wrapper").on("click",".some_button",function(){});
```

Then the event will actually be attached to `#my_wrapper`, and when fired, the target will be checked to see if it matches your selector.  This will mean that any elements added to `#my_wrapper` will still be affected even though they were added after the event was bound.

This usage of `on` is replacing the old functions of `live` and `delegate`.  It may be useful to read the documentation on them as well if you need a better understanding.

Comment: Sometimes i'm stupid - i used your way of solving this before but yesterday evening i didn't have it in mind...now it works fine - but you wrote the on method in a wrong sequence - 'click' has to be written first, and second the class you want to have the trigger for. Thanks!

Comment: Good point, I did get that backwards.  Updated my answer for anyone who stumbles upon it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a caching issue.  Try setting your onclick method to call jquery's .hide() and .show() on the section of page that you want to have change as its last two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without a fiddle or some HTML but what I think might be happening to you is that you're using the on() and binding an action to all elements with a class of .event_list_cancel, however if you create a new element with the same class it's not included in your $('.event_list_cancel') object until you reinitialize the on() method.

Have you tried re-binding the selector $('.event_list_cancel').on('click', function(e){...  after on of your divs have moved around.

Not entirely sure how re-binding the event will affect memory so you might want to off() it before you bind it again....

Comment: You know I think James' solution is more accurate than mine